# vue3 v-for columns...rows get duplicated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

silly problem but I can't get how to avoid duplicating the row.
This is my code:

```
  <div class="row" v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index">
    <Column :columnName="column.name" :columnColor="column.color" />
</div>
```

and the output is that the row itself gets duplicated, not just the columns. Image below.
I cannot understand how can I loop the columns here without duplicating the parent (the row).
[Image here - duplicated rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVg6s.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you run the `v-for` in the div and it must be in the component. Try this.

```
  <div class="row">
    <Column 
      v-for="(column, index) in columns" 
      :key="index"
      :columnName="column.name" 
      :columnColor="column.color" />
  </div>
```